# python argparse not all parameters are getting parsed

Tags: python, argparse

I ran this command

```
  ./run.sh -kryder_rate=.9   -tech_kryder_moveout=.10 -kryder_life=5 -total_runs=20  -duration=100 -purchasecost=100 -runCost=66  -horizon=20 -abc=1
```

and I got args object getting this ( Notice it did not get 'abc' and 'horizon' though I passed them

```
  Namespace(abc=None, deviceType=None, duration='100', horizon=None, kryder_life='5', kryder_rate='.9', purchasecost='100', runCost='66', tech_kryder_moveout='.10')
```

but if I reduce the number of parameters

```
   ./run.sh -kryder_rate=.9   -tech_kryder_moveout=.10 -kryder_life=5 -total_runs=20  -duration=100 -horizon=20 -abc=1
```

then it gets 'horizon' and 'abc'

```
   Namespace(abc='1', deviceType=None, duration='100', horizon='20', kryder_life='5', kryder_rate='.9', purchasecost=None, runCost=None, tech_kryder_moveout='.10')
```

Is there a limit on number of parameters to be passed?

I searched but google tells me there is no such limit.

This is how I am parsing

```
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Description of Economic Model Pgm')
    parser.add_argument('-kryder_rate','--kryder_rate', help='kryder_rate', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-kryder_life','--kryder_life', help='kryder_life', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-duration','--duration', help='duration', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-runCost','--runCost', help='runCost', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-purchasecost','--purchasecost', help='purchasecost', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-deviceType','--deviceType', help='deviceType', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-horizon','--horizon', help='horizon', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-tech_kryder_moveout','-tech_kryder_moveout',help='tech_kryder_moveout',required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-abc','--abc',help='test',required=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print args
```

Comment: Are you writing a shell script or a Python script?

Comment: Check your python command line in run.sh

Comment: You are passing the argument `-total_runs=20`, but it does not appear in your parser.

Comment: Normally the short options are a single letter long (`-a`).  You don't need the `required=False`.  But apart from the `-total_runs` error, this list of arguments works fine when given directly to a script with this parser.  So I too suspect your `run.sh`.